# Wordrpress 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permissions

Getting the following error when trying to log into my Wordpress install:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /newsite/wp-login.php on this server.

Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.3.27 mod_perl/2.0.6 Perl/v5.10.1 Server at ctcatholic.org Port 80

I have checked permissions on the `wp-config.php` and the wp-login.php pages and made sure that they were set to 644. I also made sure the folder for the admin files was set to 755.

My .htaccess file has this inside:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any thoughts on how else I can fix?

Comment: I think you would get better answers on wordpress development or webmasters part of Stackowerflow portal...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into general permissions issues with all WordPress files and folders.

(And .htaccess doesn't set permissions; the Unix file system does.)

Best thing to do is read [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

> Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on
>   your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared
>   hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself
>   (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).
>
> Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be owned or
>   group-owned by the user account used by the WordPress (which may be
>   different than the server account). For example, you may have a user
>   account that lets you FTP files back and forth to your server, but
>   your server itself may run using a separate user, in a separate
>   usergroup, such as dhapache or nobody. If WordPress is running as the
>   FTP account, that account needs to have write access, i.e., be the
>   owner of the files, or belong to a group that has write access. In the
>   latter case, that would mean permissions are set more permissively
>   than default (for example, 775 rather than 755 for folders, and 664
>   instead of 644).

So you need to `chmod` files and folders to the needed WordPress permissions scheme.